# Alamofire background working on simulator but not on device

Tags: swift, xcode, url, alamofire, background-process

As the title mentions I've set up a backgroundURL with Alamofire.  It works like a charm in simulator but on my device doesn't.  I'm sure I'm missing something here since I'm not that experienced with URL.
Here's the code I have so far:

```
class NetworkManager {

static let shared = NetworkManager()

private lazy var backgroundManager: Alamofire.SessionManager = {
    let bundleIdentifier = MyStruct.identifier
    return Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: bundleIdentifier))
}()

var backgroundCompletionHandler: (() -> Void)? {
    get{
        return backgroundManager.backgroundCompletionHandler
    }
    set{
        backgroundManager.backgroundCompletionHandler = newValue
    }
}
```

}

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession identifier: String, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    NetworkManager.shared.backgroundCompletionHandler = completionHandler
}
```

In my ViewController:

```
 func populateArrays(){  
 Alamofire.request("http://www.aps.anl.gov/Accelerator_Systems_Division/Accelerator_Operations_Physics/sddsStatus/mainStatus.sdds.gz").responseData { response in
        switch response.result{
        case .success:
            print("Validation Successful")
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        if let data = response.result.value{
```

Comment: Are you seeing any error log, warning from console when running on your phone?

Comment: No errors or anything. It just stops communicating with the url.

Comment: Can you put a break point there and make sure your http call is executed from your phone?

Comment: It's definitely being called when the app is open.  I can see it printing "validation successful".  But when the app is minimized or the phone is locked it doesn't call it.  Even a breakpoint on the handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession doesn't fire, so I know it's not calling the app delegate for some reason.

Comment: Oh, you are talking about running the request in background?

Comment: Yes, I have the appDelegate code posted above as well.

Comment: I should mention again that it's working in the background just fine in simulator.  but on my device it's not working for some reason.

Comment: Where are you calling the Alamofire request? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it.  For anyone else that has this problem you need to add the following code to your appDelegate.

```
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    var bgTask = 0
    var app = UIApplication.shared
    bgTask = app.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: {() -> Void in
        app.endBackgroundTask(bgTask)
})
```

Comment: This only worked because the task keeps the foreground request you made alive long enough to receive the response. You need to use the background session manager you created if you want the background behavior. Just creating one isn't enough.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are not using the background manager you've created. Instead of

```
Alamofire.request("http://www.aps.anl.gov...")
```

which calls the default (not background) session manager, you should use:

```
backgroundManager.request("http://www.aps.anl.gov...")
```

Which [Jon Shier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/272952/jon-shier) mentioned in the comments by the way.